# How to disable the Item in a ComboBox after it's been selected once?

Tags: vb.net

How to disable the `Item` in a `ComboBox` once it's been selected?

**Example:**
There are some `Item`s in a `ComboBox` that load from a table database. Lets call them "ECAU", "ECS5", "ECUU".
Once I select the "ECAU" and click the *Save* button, it should be disabled afterwards. So when I dare to choose again the "ECAU", it should be disabled and not be selectable again to avoid duplication of data.

I am using Vb.net and MS Access.

Comment: Please provide some code to clarify what exactly you are asking for. Have a look at the help pages on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and on [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have no already code yet. Please provide example. that is what i needed.

Comment: Well, that is not how Stack Overflow works. It's not a free code writing service.